# "CGI::param called in list context" warning in Perl

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a perl script that adds data in database

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use cPanelUserConfig;

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;
use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
use CGI;
use CGI::Cookie;
use CGI::Session qw();
use JSON;
#use MIME::Lite;

my $CFG = do "config.pl";
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $db_handle = DBI->connect ("DBI:mysql:$CFG->{database}", $CFG->{user}, $CFG->{password} ) or die "Couldn't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $decdata = decode_json($cgi->param('POSTDATA'));

my $CustomerID;# = $decdata->{'CustomerID'};
my $DeliverySlot = $decdata->{'DeliverySlot'};
my $PaymentMode = $decdata->{'PaymentMode'};
my $CustomerName = $decdata->{'CustomerName'};
my $Address = $decdata->{'Address'};
my $City = $decdata->{'City'};
my $Mobile = $decdata->{'Mobile'};

my $th = $db_handle->prepare("select customer_id from table_customers where mobile = '$Mobile'");
$th->execute() or die "Couldn't connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";
my @data = $th->fetchrow_array();
if ($data[0]) 
{
    $CustomerID = $data[0];
}
else
{
    my $sql_query = qq{insert into table_customers values (NULL, '$CustomerName', '$Address', '$Mobile', NULL, NULL)};
    my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query)    or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
    $statement->execute()   or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  
    $CustomerID = $statement->{mysql_insertid};
}

my $sql_query = qq{insert into table_orders values (NULL, '$CustomerID', NOW(),  '$PaymentMode', CURDATE(), '$DeliverySlot')};
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query)    or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
$statement->execute()   or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  


my $id = $statement->{mysql_insertid};
my $sql_query = qq{insert into table_order_status values ($id, 1, NOW())};
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query)    or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
$statement->execute()   or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  


my $aref = $decdata->{'ItemList'};

for my $element (@$aref)
{
    my $i_name = $element->{ItemName}; 
    my $i_quantity = $element->{Quantity}; 
    my $i_mrpprice = $element->{MRP}; 
    my $i_sellprice = $element->{SellPrice};
        
    my $sql_query = qq{insert into table_order_details values ('$id', 2, 2, $i_quantity, '$i_mrpprice', '$i_sellprice', '$i_name')};
    my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query)    or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
    $statement->execute()   or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  
}


$db_handle->disconnect;
  
print $cgi->header;
```

While executing the script i am seeing this error in error log file, though entry is perfect in DB.

```
[Fri Sep 25 06:57:59.276603 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 530749:tid 140571387594496] [client 61.0.172.200:16058] AH01215: [Fri Sep 25 06:57:59 2015] PlaceOrder.pl: CGI::param called in list context from PlaceOrder.pl line 19, this can lead to vulnerabilities. See the warning in "Fetching the value or values of a single named parameter"
```

Line 19 is:

```
my $decdata = decode_json($cgi->param('POSTDATA'));
```

What is this error and how to fix this. Any help or comments will be highly helpful.

Comment: Did you look at the CGI man pages for that error?  https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Well, aside from pointing out that `CGI` is [non-core because it's no longer deemed good practice](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod#CGI.pm-HAS-BEEN-REMOVED-FROM-THE-PERL-CORE) and it's worth checking out [`CGI::Alternatives`](http://search.cpan.org/~leejo/CGI-Alternatives-0.15/lib/CGI/Alternatives.pm) (I know that's not always possible, because it'd warrant a full rewrite):

```
my $decdata = decode_json(scalar $cgi->param('POSTDATA'));
```

The problem is - the `param` method [detects internally if you're asking for a list of values or a single value](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#Fetching-the-value-or-values-of-a-single-named-parameter). (See: [`wantarray()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html)). But because you're passing it into a function (`decode_json`) - it's in a list context. It seems unlikely this is what you want, given your post - so enforcing scalar context via `scalar` (or just `"".`) will do the trick

Comment: thanks bro. Could you check this issue? (your solution was applied, but they are not sure if it is correct. help would be appreciated) Thanks https://github.com/finisky/lightsquid-1.8.1/issues/1